# Using COUNT() function in Eloquent ORM (outside Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to replicate an SQL query with Eloquent ORM:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, COUNT(name) AS total
FROM tags
WHERE question_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Here is my attempt in Eloquent ORM:

```
$query = Tag::query();
$query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
    ->groupBy('name');
    ->select( array('count(name) as total') );
    ->whereNotNull('question_id');
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count(name)' in 'field list' (SQL: SELECT`COUNT(name)`AS`total`FROM`tags`WHERE`tags`.`deleted_at`IS NULL AND`question_id`IS NOT NULL GROUP BY`name`ORDER BY`name`ASC)`

... so clearly I'm not using it properly.

I found a post saying that I should use `DB::raw('COUNT(name) as total')` but I don't know where DB class is as I'm not working within Laravel. If I need to use this, how can I use it outside Laravel. I tried `use` for both:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as DB;
```

..., as these were the only classes, using grep, I could find to have a public 'function raw' within them. Query/Builder gave me an error, and Connection run OK but perhaps I didn't build the query object correctly as it gives me inconsistent results from running SQL in MySQL shell. Kinda hit a dead end, can anyone offer any help?

Thanks

Comment: I believe `DB` aliases to `Fluent`.

Comment: I tried Fluent instead of DB but `Fatal error: Class 'Fluent' not found in /var/www/vhosts/qasystem/qasystem/application/controllers/TagsController.php on line 49`

Answer (score 1):

This works, not sure if it's the cleanest way though: `$query->selectRaw('DISTINCT name, COUNT(name) as total')`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you can use both `Eloquent` and `DB::` query by use this class `use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;` if you are using Laravel 4.1.x

On top of your file

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
```

Is a good practise to inject the dependency in you class (controller or whatever it is)

```
/**
 * @var DatabaseManager
 */
private $databaseManager;

/**
 * @param DatabaseManager        $databaseManager
 */
public function __construct(DatabaseManager $databaseManager)
{
    $this->databaseManager = $databaseManager;
}
```

Then in your method, I'm just assuming your table name and fields here...

```
 public function youAwesomeMethod(){
    $query = Tag::select([
        'tags.id',
        'tags.name',
        $this->databaseManager->raw("count(tags.id) AS count_tags")
    ])->whereNotNull('tags.question_id')
      ->orderBy('tags.name', 'ASC')
      ->groupBy('count_tags');
    // Do something else if needed
    return $query
}
```

This should do the trick. Also you will access to `count_tags` as a normal Eloquent attribute `tag->count_tags`